# How to get the first employee entrance in a day near his shift

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have an **employee_attendance** table (`SQL Server 2012`) with the following columns:

- AttendanceId (Identity)
- EmployeeId
- Timestamp (in or out card punch)
- AccessCode ( I = IN, O = OUT )

Here is the **SQL Fiddle** with some sample data: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ba8a1/1

I know that these employees can work on any day on any of the 3 shifts we have:

1. Shift A (From 07:00 to 15:00)
2. Shift B (From 15:00 to 23:00)
3. Shift C (From 23:00 to 07:00 next day)

> So what I need is to know for each employee in a selected day (the sample data has just one day and has been filtered to show only **IN** records, so only **IN** access to the company) is the first `Timestamp` that is near (below or above) the Shift entrance.

Here is an image of what the SQL Fiddle data should look like after applying the right script:

[image]

Comment: yay for sql fiddles with sample data! <3

Comment: For employeeid 116, the timestamp that you indicated is correct is 45 minutes before the start of the shift while another timestamp (15:25:43) is only 25 minutes away.  So you're not looking for the nearest, correct?  What if 14:15:35 was actually 12:15:35?  Would the employee be really early or 25 minutes late?  Is the data clean enough to say there will always be only one shift for each employee in a given day, and we can always use the early timestamp if it exists and if not use the late timestamp?

Comment: How do you know what shift someone is on?

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 1):

Since you have SQL Server 2012, you can use TimeFromParts and "mod 8" everything to minimize the work...

```
select employeeId,
       accessCode,
       minDiff = MIN(ABS(DATEDIFF(TIMEFROMPARTS(DATEPART(HH,t.timestamp) % 8,
                                               (DATEPART(MI,t.timestamp),
                                               (DATEPART(S,t.timestamp),0,0),
                                  TIMEFROMPARTS(7,
                                               (DATEPART(MI,t.timestamp),
                                               (DATEPART(S,t.timestamp))
from table t
were t.timestamp is in a given daily range
```

So, since your shift changes (7,15,23) are all "mod 8 = 7" I just compare the hour portion of the timestamp "mod 8" to "7" -- that way I don't need to run the query three times.

Comment: I'm liking the elegance of mod 8, I will have to remember this the next time I come across a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

SQLFiddle (thanks for providing sample data): http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ba8a1/7/0

Query:

```
declare @day datetime = '5-20-15' --not necessary, but included for more flexibility; you can just hardcode the date below if you want

SELECT *, '7:00:00 shift' as Shift
, abs(datediff(minute, timestamp, @day + '7:00:00')) as TimeDiff
into #temp
FROM employee_attendance
union all
SELECT *, '15:00:00 shift'
, abs(datediff(minute, timestamp, @day + '15:00:00'))
FROM employee_attendance
union all
SELECT *, '23:00:00 shift'
, abs(datediff(minute, timestamp, @day + '23:00:00'))
FROM employee_attendance

select * from (
  select *
  , row_number() over (partition by EmployeeID order by TimeDiff) as RowN
  from #temp
  ) a
where RowN = 1
```

Explanation:

1. Create a row for each employee, for each shift start time.
2. Calculate the difference between the actual start time and the clock-in time listed.  Take absolute value because the original request is looking for the closest clock-in, not necessarily before the shift started.
3. Use row_number to identify the row for each employee with the shortest difference to a shift start time.
4. Return only the closest row to the shift start time.

As others have noted, this assumes that an employee only has one shift per day, and that the closest clock-in to the shift time is the one that is valid.  For a single shift per day system, it might make more sense to come up with alternate criteria - for example, looking at the absolute earliest clock-in, or the earliest clock-in within a given window (say 6:30 to 7:30, for the 7:00 shift), but that is not what this requestor has asked for.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @TabAlleman - I have added more details.